# Can someone explain what will happen in the following function if the array is out of index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexing, syntax

```
function remove(items, item){
    for (let i =0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i] === item){
            return [ ...items.slice(0, i), ...items.slice(i+1)]
        }
    }
}
```

My code is above. I'm curious about the return statement.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are you seeing that you do not expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement will be executed only if there is a matched case of `item` inside `items`.

If `item` matches then the function is making a new array consisting with the element of the previous values and the next values of the `item`. That means return array contains all the array elements from the passed array except the item that matched.

This function is buggy in a sense that it does not remove all the `item` from `items` array, and does not return anything when there is no match.

Here is a updated version:

```
function remove(items, item) {
  let newItems = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] !== item) {
        // if current item is not equal to searching item, than it 
        // should be in the returned array.
        newItems.push(items[i];
    }
    // you should not return if there is match, in that case multiple 
    // matching item would not be removed from items array 
  }
  // always return the result array whether there is a match or not.
  return newItems; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function remove(items, item) {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] === item) {
      return items.slice(0, i).concat(items.slice(i + 1, items.length));
    }
  }
}
```